# Ajax request to rails controller not returning databsae records when passed a range

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am making an ajax request to an action in my rails controller that returns a range of model instances from the database when passed an upper and lower limit. For some reason if i request the models like this Model.messages[params[:lower_limit].to_i..params[:upper_limit]] it doesnt return anything even though it works when I put the numbers in myself.

Here is my code below:

The ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '/messages/get',
        dataType: 'script',
        data: {lowerLimit: $('.message-list li').length, 
                     upperLimit: $('.message-list li').length + 10, 
                     resource: 'Event',
                     id: $('#event-id').text() }
    });
```

The controller:

```
def get
  @resource = params[:resource].constantize.find(params[:id])
  @messages = @resource.messages[(params[:lowerLimit].to_i)..(params[:upperLimit].to_i)]
end
```

My success function currently looks like this:

```
console.log(<%= params[:lowerLimit] %>,<%= params[:upperLimit] %>);
$('.message-list').append('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: "partials/message_list", locals: { messages: @messages, list_container: false }) %>');
ajaxInProgress = false;
if (<%= escape_javascript (!@messages.any?).to_s %>) { needsUpdate = false };
```

After the request has completed it logs two numbers to the parameters so i assume they are definately correct on the server side. Can anyone think of a reason that might cause this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add your `routes.rb` and the console output?

Comment: you would be doing yourself a favor by installing a debugger gem such as `byebug` and calling it from your controller. Then you can see exactly what the params values are at runtime.

Comment: What are your  doing in `message` method? Would you share it? You are passing an `Array` that's first element is `range object` Is it what you are intended for?

Comment: Try to comment out the `$.ajax()` block and `console.log()` the `$('.message-list li').length`, `$('.message-list li').length + 10` and `$('#event-id').text()`. Make sure you can see all 3 of them.